# switch div left / right not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Brief Explanation:** I have div1 and div2 inside main . On **right click**, context menu opens which has a button called `switch`.

On clicking this button div1 and div2 switch positions but they are not switching properly

Requirement: Div should switch left and right but it is going below the other one.

**attached pics for your reference:** 
[image]

Now when you click switch, the right one goes down instead of left, see below:
[image]

Here is my [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/ohw25Ltf/7/) and code:

```js
$(document).on("contextmenu","div", function(event) {
      
     // alert("right clicked");
      event.stopPropagation();
      this.clickedElement  = $(this);
      event.preventDefault();
      $(this.clickedElement).addClass('selecteddiv');
      $(".custom-menu4").show();
      
       $(".custom-menu4 li").unbind().click(function(){
       
       switch($(this).attr("data-action"))
   { 
      case "second":
       $(".custom-menu4").hide();
       $(".selecteddiv").removeClass('selecteddiv');
       break;
       
       case "first":
       $('.click').find('.switch').eq(0).appendTo($('.click'));
       break;
       
       
   }
       
       })
     
 
     // alert("add");
      });


$('.click').click(function (evt) {
  var $div = $(evt.target).first('.switch');
  $div.next('.switch').after($div);
});




/*    $(document).unbind().on("click", function(devent) {
      devent.stopPropagation();     $(".selecteddiv").removeClass('selecteddiv');
   
      alert("remove");
        
      });  
    */
```

```css
 .selecteddiv {
    border: 1px solid rgb(180, 13, 172);
  }
  
  .custom-menu4 {
    display: none;
    
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<div class="click container-fluid" >

<div class="row">
<div class="switch col-sm-6 bg-primary">Hello</div> 
<div class="switch  col-sm-6 bg-secondary">World</div>
</div>

</div>

<ul class='custom-menu4'>
    <li data-action = "first">Switch</li>
    <li data-action = "second">Cancel</li>
</ul>
```

> Please update jsfiddle and dont give any id to div's in the solution.

Thank you for your valuable time.

Comment: After the switch, one of the divs is no longer inside your `div.row`. In this line `$('.click').find('.switch').eq(0).appendTo($('.click'));` you need to append to `.row` instead of `.click`.

Comment: That's strange, I don't see the problem. The divs keep being side by side after flipping. Does this happen only at certain screen widths?

Comment: hii, this is not working seemless, if i am adding 1 more similar `<div>` below it starts acting differently, try here- http://jsfiddle.net/ohw25Ltf/13/

Answer (score 3):

Your are pulling the buttons out of the ".row" by appending to the wrong element.

modify line 21 from

```
$('.click').find('.switch').eq(0).appendTo($('.click'));
```

to

```
$('.click').find('.switch').eq(0).appendTo($('.row'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Iulius90/mzy7nLqx/

Comment: hii, this is not working seemless, if i am adding 1 more similar `<div>` below it starts acting differently, try here- http://jsfiddle.net/ohw25Ltf/13/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.click').find('.switch').eq(0).appendTo($('.row'));
```

This will fix it.

Comment: hii, this is not working seemless, if i am adding 1 more similar `<div>` below it starts acting differently, try here- http://jsfiddle.net/ohw25Ltf/13/